# Multiple INSERT/UPDATE with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

can you suggest me the best solution to make multiple INSERT and UPDATE at the same time, please?

I use a SELECT to retrieve records from a table and I let the user to update the content of each record if he checks the checkbox "insert".
At the moment, I use a form button for each set of records.

Since there can be lots of records, I would like to use only a single "form" and a single "form button" for all the data and to update or insert only the set of records when the user checks the checkbox. Is it possible? If yes, how? Can you give me any suggestions, please?

```
$sql = "select * from table1 where nome_area like '%$nome_area%' AND nome_voce like '%$nome_voce%'";

    $rs = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Database Error: ' . mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows( $rs );

    if($num >= 1 ){         

        echo "<table align=\"center\" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=100>";

        echo "<tbody><tr><td width=\"20%\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )){

            echo "<form name=\"form\" id=\"form\" action=\"update.php\" method=\"post\">";
        echo "<table data-role=\"table\" class=\"ui-responsive\"  cellspacing=\"20\" ";
        echo "<tbody>";

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<font text color=\"red\">Insert</font> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"insert\" value=\"1\" id=\"insert\"></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td><b>Tipo Area</b>:</td><td>".$row['nome_area']. " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Nome della voce</b>: </td><td> " .$row['nome_voce'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"id_voce\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" . $row['ID'] . "\">";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"nome_azienda\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$name. "\">"; // azienda
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"nome_area\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$row['nome_area']. "\">";
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"nome_voce\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$row['nome_voce']. "\">";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"> <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Associa la voce di contratto all'azienda\" id=\"search-btn\" style=\"height:50px; \"; /></td></tr>";
            echo "</tbody></table>";
                echo "</form>";



}

echo "</td></tr></tbody></table>";

    }else{
        // if no records found
        echo "<br><br><b>Nessun risultato trovato!</b></div>";
    }
```

In my update.php page, I just read the form values and INSERT them into my table:

```
.....
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table2 (id_voce,associazione, nome_azienda, nome_area, nome_voce, created_date) VALUES('$id_voce','$associa','$nome_azienda','$nome_area','$nome_voce','$time')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to generate a sequential row id # for each row.  Let's assume this is your collection of rows from the database:

```
$rs = array(
    array('ID'=>'111', 'nome_area'=>'first nome area',  'nome_voce'=>'first nome voce'),
    array('ID'=>'222', 'nome_area'=>'second nome area', 'nome_voce'=>'second nome voce'),
    array('ID'=>'333', 'nome_area'=>'third nome area',  'nome_voce'=>'third nome voce'),
);
```

Now create the table with a checkbox that has a sequential ID number:

```
$rowcounter = 0;
foreach ($rs as $row) {
    $rowcounter++;
    echo <<<HERE
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_{$rowcounter}_checkbox" value="1" /></td>
  <td>
    ID: {$row['ID']}
    <input type="hidden" name="row_{$rowcounter}_ID" value="{$row['ID']}" />
  </td>
  <td>
    Tipo Area: {$row['nome_area']}
    <input type="hidden" name="row_{$rowcounter}_nome_area" value="{$row['nome_area']}" />
  </td>
  <td>
    Nome della voce: {$row['nome_voce']} 
    <input type="hidden" name="row_{$rowcounter}_nome_voce" value="{$row['nome_voce']}" />
  </td>
</tr>

HERE;
}
```

When the form is submitted, you can find all checkboxes that are checked, then process the other form values related to that unique row ID:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    if (preg_match("/^row_(\d+)_checkbox$/",$key,$matches) && $val == "1") {

        $rowid = $matches[1];

        $ID = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_ID"];
        $nome_area = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_area"];
        $nome_voce = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_voce"];

        print "The checkbox was checked for the row with this data:\n";
        print "ID: $ID\n";
        print "nome_area: $nome_area\n";
        print "nome_voce: $nome_voce\n";
    }
}
```

**EDIT** For your own HTML code, it would be something like this:

```
$rowcounter = 0;
echo "<form name=\"form\" id=\"form\" action=\"update.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<table data-role=\"table\" class=\"ui-responsive\"  cellspacing=\"20\" ";
echo "<tbody>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )){
    $rowcounter++;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<font text color=\"red\">Insert</font> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\"  name=\"row_{$rowcounter}_insert\" value=\"1\" id=\"insert\"></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Tipo Area</b>:</td><td>".$row['nome_area']. " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Nome della voce</b>: </td><td> " .$row['nome_voce'] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"row_{$rowcounter}_id_voce\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" . $row['ID'] . "\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"row_{$rowcounter}_nome_azienda\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$name. "\">"; // azienda
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"row_{$rowcounter}_nome_area\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$row['nome_area']. "\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"row_{$rowcounter}_nome_voce\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$row['nome_voce']. "\">";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\"> <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Associa la voce di contratto all'azienda\" id=\"search-btn\" style=\"height:50px; \"; /></td></tr>";
echo "</tbody></table>";
echo "</form>";
```

and a form processor something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    if (preg_match("/^row_(\d+)_insert$/",$key,$matches)) {
        $rowid = $matches[1];
        $nome_id_voce = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_id_voce"];
        $nome_area    = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_area"];
        $nome_voce    = $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_voce"];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer! but how can I fill the array after the SELECT? I'm studying your solution.. it seems to be a little bit complicated for me! :(

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can write a loop around your HTML table-generating code (using a `$rowcounter` to ensure the fields in each row have unique names), then process them once the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, David! It works very well! I just can't read $_POST["row_{$rowid}_nome_id_voce"] since the variable $nome_id_voce is always NULL. I'm trying to understand the reason..

Comment: I solved it!!! Everything works well!!! Now i just have to insert the SQL query in the loop!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  If you found it helpful I would be obliged if you would "accept" my answer (clicking the check mark to the left of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for performing insertion of new record or updation of existing ones (based on PK)

Answer (score 0):

You need adding record id to element name. Example:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" style=\"width:0; height:0; border:0; background-color:inherit; overflow:hidden;\" name=\"nome_voce_". $row['ID'] ."\"  maxlength=\"50\" value=\"" .$row['nome_voce']. "\">";
```

You can get all variables in update.php and prepare multiple insert command.
Also there are js based table editor, you can use them. Easy one: http://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/mCtuA

Comment: The problem is that I dont know how to get undefined form values in update.php file in order to update it..